# Is it possible to grab the last line of wget?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, grep

```
$ wget --output-document=/dev/null http://website.com/file.jpg

Resolving speedtest.sea01.softlayer.com... 67.228.112.250
Connecting to speedtest.sea01.softlayer.com|67.228.112.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1986284 (1.9M) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

2011-10-02 22:38:04 (337 KB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [1986284/1986284]
```

Everything works above, but I would like to know how to store the last line in a variable OR pass it through GREP -> /((.+))/

(I'm trying to parse for the average KB/s)

Comment: Why don't you use an actual speed testing program instead of `wget`?

Comment: What do you get if you pipe it to `tail -1`?

Comment: @Borealid: Can you suggest an actual speed testing program?

Comment: @Gabe The `ab` tool will serve. If you're doing end-to-end testing, I usually use `iperf`, which is wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect the output of the command.  For example:

```
$ wget --output-document=/dev/null http://website.com/file.jpg 2>&1 | tee /tmp/somefile
$ tail -n 1 /tmp/somefile
```

Comment: Or you can use `-o` option instead of redirect:
`wget --output-document=/dev/null -o /tmp/somefile`

Answer (score 2):

If you have apache installed, you can use Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool:

```
ab -n1 http://website.com/file.jpg | grep -F 'Transfer rate:'
```

you get output like:

```
Transfer rate:          1722.38 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -O /dev/null  http://website.com/file.jpg 2>&1 |
sed -n '\%/dev/null%!d;s/.*(//;s/).*//p'
```

On my system, the final output line is empty, otherwise the `sed` addressing would be simpler.  This is on Ubuntu out of the box; if your `sed` is different, you may need to adapt the script slightly.

(I tried with `grep -o '(.*)'` at first, but there is other text in parentheses earlier in the output from `wget`.)

Comment: As a belated aside, `curl` is generally more versatile and scripting friendly. Maybe try `variable=$(curl -S -o /dev/null -w '%{speed_download}' http://url.example.net/file.jpg)`